# Answered Elsewhere

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[Should a parent bless a child resting one hand or both?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/should-a-parent-bless-a-child-resting-one-hand-or-both)

The question was answered by-the-way in [an answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7727) on a different question. Is this considered duplicate?

If not - should the answer be copied/linked to/other?

Comment: See comments on my answer, below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this considered duplicate?

No. I just looked briefly for a canonical Meta Stack Overflow post or Stack Exchange Blog post that says so directly and couldn't find one, but, nonetheless, closure as duplicate is for duplication of a question, not of things mentioned in answers.

(Sometimes having the same answer is an indication questions may be duplicates. But not always, and certainly not in this case.)

> If not - should the answer be copied/linked to/other?

In my opinion, either quoting or summarizing the relevant parts of the preexisting answer, and providing a link to it as your source, is a good way to go.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1339/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks. Actually, the first of the two questions I block-quoted in my answer is a duplicate of that; maybe the question above should be reduced to the second....